# The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)

Tags: ios, swift, ftp

I'm trying to upload an image to a **FTP** server using `swift 4`

I used [FileProvider](https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider) which is a library for Ftp connection iOS

anyway I'm checking the provider is reachable. and Im getting this error

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)

this is the full error object:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=ftp://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:21/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=ftp://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:21/, NSURL=ftp://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:21/}

this is my code:

```
 self.ftpProvider!.isReachable { (flag, error) in
        if flag {
            print("RIZK:--- provider is reachable ")

            let progress = self.ftpProvider!.copyItem(localFile: localURL, to: "/files/\(imageName)", overwrite: true, completionHandler: { (error) in
                if error == nil {
                    print("RIZK:-- Ready to upload")
                }else{
                    print("RIZK:--\(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                }
            })

            print(progress?.fractionCompleted ?? 0)

        }else{
            print("RIZK:--- provider not reachable, with error \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "") ")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `print(error)` to see the whole error.

Comment: @rmaddy, I edited my question please check it